# C# Convert mm/d/yyyy to YYYYmmDD

Tags: c#

I'm trying to covnert 11/6/2012 to 20120611 is there an easy way to convert the values?

I tried `DateTime.ParseExact("11/6/2012", "yyyy-MM-dd", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString();` but i believe the `/` in the string is screwing it up.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your string `"11/6/2012"` doesn't match your format `"yyyy-MM-dd"`. It is not the back slash.

Your format should be `"dd/M/yyyy"` where:

- `yyyy` stands for 4 digit year
- `M` stands for single or double digit Month (for parsing)
- `dd` stands for double digit day

If you are expecting day part to be single digit like `1`,`2` or double digit like `11`, `28` etc. then you can use a single `d` in the format, which would parse both single digit and double digits day part. The current format `"dd/M/yyyy"` would require days like `1` to be `01`.

For Parsing:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact("11/6/2012", "dd/M/yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

For generated your output string:

```
string formattedDate = dt.ToString("yyyyMMdd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

This will give you: `formattedDate = "20120611"`

For for information see: [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Your solution is of course right Habib. I just want to give a tip: If OP uses a different culture that's it's [`DateSeparator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.dateseparator%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is not `/`, code will be broken (even if _string_ and _format_ has the same format) because [`/` format specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#dateSeparator) has a special meaning in custom date and time format strings as _replace me with the current culture date separator_

Comment: @SonerGönül, `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` will take care of that.

Comment: Of course, that's why I wrote _If OP uses a different culture that's it's DateSeparator is not /_ `:)`

Answer (score 1):

The `DateTime.ParseExact` function does exactly what its name says i.e. to the slashes and hyphens. For an example, check out:

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

As said by @Habib, if you use "dd/M/yyyy" it will do the trick.

If you want further info about formats check out:

http://www.geekzilla.co.uk/View00FF7904-B510-468C-A2C8-F859AA20581F.htm